# (didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation) called after [stopUpdatingLocation]

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm using `CLLocationManager` to get the longitude and latitude of the device. Everything goes very well until I call `[startUpdatingLocation]` while Wifi is off (Location Service is still enabled): The alert "Turn on WiFi to improve location accuracy" showed off, and then the delegate method `[didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation]` is called continuously even though I've called `[stopUpdatingLocation]` inside the method. I've searched in Apple's documentation and haven't found any explanations for this, did anyone had the same issue before?

My code when I init the location manager:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

and my locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:FromLocation:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; //<--I did stop the location manager here
//.... do something
```

Comment: could you provide a bit more context as to where you are implementing your stopUpdating method? there may be something else looping which is throwing the Locationmanager out.

Comment: This still doesn't give us any info as to where the problem is - we need more than 3 lines of code to see where the problem is.

Comment: the only reason its getting call again after [stopUpdatingLocation] , is that [startUpdatingLocation] somehow got  called again and again by some looping or event.

Comment: I guessed so, but there's actually no calls to [startUpdatingLocation] again. The weird thing is, this only happen when I receive the alert "Turn on WiFi to improve location accuracy"